# Google is not crawling my blog pages - React website with wordpress blog

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, seo, cpanel, blogs

I created a react website that is hosted in cPanel with a blog hosted on Wordpress, let's call it mydomain.com. I installed Wordpress on the /blog slug in the cPanel and a link to /blog in the nav bar. Everything is rendering perfectly. But when we crawl mydomain.com, it shows all of the pages of my website that have routes in App.js, but it does not show any blogs (eg mydomain.com/blog/myreallycoolblog). I don't know a lot about SEO and I am completely stumped.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?